# Error 3134 in VBA pass-through QueryDef to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, pass-through

How do I work around MS Access Error 3134 in VBA pass-through querydef to SQL Server?

```vb
Dim strQuery As String, strPlutus As String
Dim qDef As QueryDef
Dim db As DAO.Database

strPlutus = "qryPT_toPlutus"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qDef = db.CreateQueryDef(strPlutus)

    strQuery = "SELECT " & vbCrLf
    strQuery = strQuery & "top 100 " & vbCrLf
    strQuery = strQuery & "Carrier_UID " & vbCrLf
    strQuery = strQuery & ", CarrierName " & vbCrLf
    strQuery = strQuery & "from vw_ODBC_Carriers " & vbCrLf
    strQuery = strQuery & "where TableKey=141 " & vbCrLf
    strQuery = strQuery & "and Carrier_UID <> 1;" & vbCrLf

    qDef.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=OAK;Description=OAK;UID=xxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=OAK"

    qDef.SQL = strQuery
    qDef.ODBCTimeout = 600
    qDef.Close

    db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblCarriers " & strPlutus
```

Comment: What is error 3134? Also, you can use code blocks to display code in a more readable format.

Comment: Sure thing. 3134 error is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement".

Comment: Sorry about the missing code block here you go:

Comment: Dim strSQL strQuery As String
Dim qryPT_toPlutus As QueryDef, qDef As QueryDef
Dim db As DAO.Database                                                             
   Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qDef = db.CreateQueryDef(strPlutus)qDef.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=OAK;Description=AegisOAK;UID=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=OAK"                                             
        qDef.SQL = strQuery
        qDef.ODBCTimeout = 600
        qDef.Close                                                                
         db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblCarriers " & strPlutus

Comment: Please edit your original question to show your code (do not use comments). To display the code in a readable format, insert 4 spaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: The variable *strPlutus* is never defined. Should it be *strQuery*?

Comment: strPlutus is defined on the first line above. It is then initiated with the name of the queryDef.

Comment: Select from sql server insert into access?

Comment: Any reason for using a pass.through query instead of linking `vw_ODBC_Carriers` or a view on your select statement to access (or the opposite way, link access table to sql server) and use standard query (no sql server specific commands, no exec time gains)?

Comment: OMG. This is an old habit of mine where the "official" IT staff did not agree with us non-IT staff of linking to production databases this way (End users might run a run-away query) so I would write pass-through queries so as to keep the IT staff happy. Also, I realize within Access I can "hide" the tables from view, although the more sophisticated end-user just might figure that one out. Thanks @ComputerVersteher for making my weekend?

Comment: You can [link at runtime](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/194862-programatically-linking-tables) and delete link, when finished!

Comment: Just recognized by @Andres anser, that `qryPT_toPlutus` is a linked view

Answer (score 1):

Your Pass-through query is ok, the problem is with this:

```vb
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblCarriers " & strPlutus
```

which is

```vb
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblCarriers qryPT_toPlutus"
```

which is obviously a syntax error and should be

```vb
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblCarriers SELECT * FROM " & strPlutus
```

Note #1: `SELECT TOP 100` should have an `ORDER BY` clause (but it's probably just for testing).

Note #2: `qDef.Close` doesn't do anything and can be removed. If anything, use `Set qDef = Nothing`, but since it's a local variable, that's redundant too.

Comment: does not the db.Execute use the "contents" of the variable strPlutus which contains the " SELECT FROM" equate to what you are saying here? Does the SELECT FROM need to be in the "INSERT INTO" string in order to work! The "SELECT FROM" is present in the variable strPlutus .

Comment: No... please re-read or debug your code and check the contents of `strPlutus`. You  define the PT-query, and then use it by its name. @JPQ